# I need to pass errors back from the model to the controller when a csv file is uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling

Model:

```
  def self.import(csv_file)
    order = Order.new
    if order.valid? == false
      nil
    else
      CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
        Order.create! row.to_hash
      end
    end
  end
```

Controller:

```
  def import
    Order.import(params[:csv_file].tempfile)
    if nil
      redirect_to '/orders/upload_page', flash[:error] = "#{@order.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
    else
      redirect_to '/orders/upload_page', flash[:notice] = "upload successful"
    end
  end
```

form partial:

```
<%= form_tag import_orders_path, multipart: true do %>
  <div class="controls">
  <%= file_field_tag :csv_file, accept: 'csv', :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-info' %>    
  <%= submit_tag "Upload Orders", :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

render page:

```
<div class ="container" style="margin-top:85px;" align="center">
  <h2>Orders CSV Upload</h2>
  <%= render partial: 'upload_form' %>
</div>
```

What I need to somehow do is ideally two things: 1. I need to supply a notice for errors or success and 2. either supply a notice with the errors OR return a csv file with the rows that contain errors, both would be like cake with a spoon.  I am not entirely sure how to create a tempfile where the errored data would be spit into and then returned as I am processing the csv file from tempfile as it is.

There is only one validation in the model that the csv uploader currently has to pass and it is `validates_uniqueness_of :batch, :scope => :projectid`

As you can see I have tried flash[:error] to no effect; it does nothing.  I can see in the console that when I insert data I know is purposely trying to violate the validation that it doesn't get uploaded and passes back a Order Exists from the active record.

I am also working on making the submit button available only when there is a file selected.  If there is any advice on that I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's write some example code on how we would like to access the errors in the controller.

```
#controller
def import
  @import = Order.import(params[:csv_file].tempfile)

  if @import.successful?
    flash[:notice] = "#{@import.success_count} orders successfully imported"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Import failed with #{@import.error_count} errors"
  end  

  # access all orders with errors in the view using @import.failed_records
  redirect_to '/orders/upload_page'
end
```

This implies that `import` needs to return an object which responds to `success_count`, `error_count`, `failed_records` and `successful?`.

```
class OrderImporter
  def initialize(file)
    @file = file
    @success_count = 0
    @failed_records = []
  end

  def call   
    CSV.foreach(@file, headers: true) do |row|
      order = Order.new(row.to_hash)
      save_and_report(order)
    end

    self #ensure that this object is returned upon call
  end

  def success_count 
    # default to 0 at start
    @success_count
  end

  def failed_records
    @failed_records
  end

  def error_count
    failed_records.count
  end

  def successful?
    failed_records.empty? && success_count > 0
  end

  private

  def save_and_report(order)
    # avoid the bang version (save!) as we don't need to handle exceptions here.
    if order.save
      @success_count += 1
    else
      @failed_records << order
    end
  end   
end
```

We can call the `OrderImporter` from `Order.import`.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.import(file)
    importer = OrderImporter.new(file).call
  end
end
```

Or, we can bypass `Order` and directly use the `OrderImporter` in the controller:

`@import = OrderImporter.new(params[:csv_file].tempfile).call`

This gives you full access to the results of the upload in the controller. I'll leave it up to you to populate the flash or create a CSV for download.

Comment: Yea you're using a separate controller for handling the import.  I originally was going to go this way.  I can still probably do that; it will take a while to re-work my site to do it that way.

Comment: This way is bypassing the model validation.  It imported an order that should not have been able to be imported due to the validation.  if I try and use @import = OrderImporter.new(params[:csv_file].tempfile).call

Comment: if I do it with just @import = Order.import(params[:csv_file].tempfile) I get the expected, but it says with 0 errors.

Comment: Actually, I am even more wrong; it is just failing to import anything.

Comment: @user2867882: Are the order records being created as expected?

Comment: @user2867882: Is it returning the records in `errors` then?

Comment: I have tried different variations of this code now; the only time it actually imports orders is when I don't use the model.  The problem is then it also skips the validation and imports orders that violate the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually have a full answer, but here is where I am at right now; still need some help.

Model

```
  def self.import(csv_file)
    CSV.foreach(csv_file, headers: true) do |row|
      order = Order.find_or_initialize_by(projectid: row["projectid"], batch: row["batch"])
      order.assign_attributes(row.to_hash)
      if order.valid?
        order.save!
        return true
      else
        order.errors
        return false
      end
    end
  end
```

Controller

```
  def import
    if params[:csv_file].present?
      result = Order.import(params[:csv_file].tempfile)
      if result == true
        flash[:notice] = "upload successful"
      elsif result == false
        flash[:error] = "Error uploading"
      end
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Please choose a file"
    end

    redirect_to '/orders/upload_page'
  end
```

form

```
<%= form_tag import_orders_path, multipart: true do %>
  <div class="controls">
  <% flash.each do |type, msg| %>
  <h4><%= msg.humanize %><h4>
  <% end %>
  <%= file_field_tag :csv_file, accept: 'csv', :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-info' %>    
  <%= submit_tag "Upload Orders", :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I can get the initial upload to work, but it always tells me error uploading; nothing I do changes that.  That might have to do with how I am trying to do the messages on the form since I also get other error messages on the form that shouldn't be there.  I am somewhat less concerned with the messages being displayed, though getting that working would be good too.  I am more concerned with the failure to function on update.

The other thing that is not working is the record is not updating.  If I enter a record that already exists I thought that this should update the record.  It's not updating.

Comment: I am fairly certain that the issue is with the form

Comment: Okay, the flash messages are working mostly now.  I still get flashes from other methods if I go straight back to the upload page; very strange and I think that it has to do with the form flash code. 

The model code still won't allow updating; I am not sure why.